# Can I sync progress between two different Xbox Live accounts?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-network

I played GTA 5 on a friend's account, but when I made my own account there was no way for me to retrieve the progress even though we played it on the same Xbox One, and had both our accounts saved on the same console.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you trying to sync a story mode (offline) save?  Also, are you on Xbox One or Xbox 360?  Please give more information about your scenario!

Comment: I don't know of any game that lets a player transfer save data to another user

Comment: Saves are stored on a per profile basis. It doesn't matter if the accounts are on the same system.

Comment: I am on xbox 1 and yes, I am playing storymode

Answer (score 2):

Xbox does not support this functionality.  Saves are tied to a profile.  It will not matter if the saves are on the same or another console.

For Xbox 360, you can use some third party tools to move saves between profiles (google xbox game saving for some tutorials, such as the modio or horizon tool).

For Xbox One, I don't believe the third party tools support this generation of console.

Please note, the practise of using such tools takes you outside of the user agreement so are at risk to bans or "gamerscore resets".  Googling the same terms above should also touch on the risks involved.

Answer (score 1):

Some games allow to copy saved data, do not think GTA is one of them. But you will be unable to earn achievements, off of this data.